# open vsto thisworkbook from windows application

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2013, vsto

I am trying to add VSTO Excel Document Level project using an existing .xlsx document to an existing windows form application project. I have put reference from the Windows App to the VSTO project and manage to import the VSTO project into the Windows App, in addition I have also imported Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in the Windows App.

Question is, how to open the Excel Doc in the VSTO from within the Windows App and link withevents the "Thisworkbook" of the Excel doc in the VSTO (like calling globals.thisworkbook)?

I have tried to open directly the excel doc from the win app, however, the code within the vsto doesn't work.

Bunches of thanks for your help!

Comment: Please show us the code to open the excel workbook from within your WinForms application.

Comment: I think I have solved the problem. All I need to do is to first build the VSTO Document before opening it with Win form app.  But they are mere separate project.